# Can the centrifugal inertial force, acting on ultrarelativistic electron in a circular orbit, be expressed in terms of its kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, rotational-kinematics

From classical mechanics we know that centrifugal inertial force, acting on an electron in a circular orbit of radius $R$ in relatively slow motion ($v \ll  c$), can be expressed in terms of its kinetic energy $K$:

$$F = \frac{mv^2}{R} = \frac{2K}{R}.$$

For relativistic and ultrarelativistic electrons this relation is, obviously, not valid. Can the centrifugal force on ultrarelativistic electron still be expressed in terms of $K$ and $R$?

Comment: I think Bohr's model is not the realistic model of an atom, so talking about it wouldn't, t land you anywhere.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh Bohr’s model is about atoms. The scenario I was thinking about was about ultrarelativistic electrons revolving around a positively charged copper ball of macroscopic size, say, $R = 5$ cm. Such a ball in high vacuum conditions can be charged high enough that the electron revolving around it would have to be ultrarelativistic. So the question stands.

Answer (score 0):

Since the motion of the electron is perpendicular to the force direction, we can use the following equation for the centripetal force using the relativistic [transverse mass: [See Eq. (5c), and use $\boldsymbol {a.u=0}.$]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(special_relativity)#Acceleration_and_force)

$$F=-\gamma m_0a=-\gamma m_0\frac{v^2}{R}\space. \tag{1}$$

For the relativistic kinematic energy we have:

$$K=(\gamma-1)m_0c^2\space, \tag{2}$$

which implies:

$$\gamma m_0=\frac{K+m_0c^2}{c^2}\space. \tag{3}$$

Inserting Eq. (3) in Eq. (1), we finally get:

$$F=-\left(\frac{K+m_0c^2}{c^2}\right) \frac{v^2}{R}\space. \tag{4}$$

**ADDED:**

Now you have to find $v^2$ in terms of $K$. From Eq. (2), we have:

$$\frac{1}{\gamma^2}=\frac{m_0^2c^4}{\left(K+m_0c^2\right)^2}\rightarrow v^2=c^2\left(1-\frac{m_0^2c^4}{(K+m_0c^2)^2}\right)\space. \tag{5}$$

Substituting Eq. (5) into Eq. (4), and after simplification, we get:

$$F=-\frac{K}{R}×\frac{K+2m_0c^2}{K+m_0c^2}\space. \tag{6}$$

Therefore, you can see that that the relation is no longer Newtonian.

Answer (score 0):

Starting essentially from the same premise as Mohammad Javanshiry's answer, I get a slightly different result:

$$F=m\frac{v^2}{R}=\frac{E}{c^2}\frac{v^2}{R}=\frac{Kv^2}{Rc^2}\frac{E}{K}=\frac{K}{R}\frac{\gamma \beta^2}{\gamma-1}=\frac{K}{R}\frac{\beta^2}{1-\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}=\frac{K}{R}({1+\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}),$$

where, as usual:

$$\beta = \dfrac{v}{c}, \gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}.$$

Thus, centrifugal inertial force for *any ultrarelativistic charge particle* depends $-$ just like in classical mechanics $-$ on two parameters only, its kinetic energy and the radius of the orbit:

$$F=\frac{K}{R}.$$

Comment: Your calculations are correct, and the second equation is similar to mine providing you rewrite $\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$ as a function of $K$. I just don't understand how you deduced $F=K/R$ in the last equation.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry The question was about *ultrarelativistic electrons*, i.e. by definition for electrons with $E/m_0c^2 \gg 1$ (which is the same thing as  $K/m_0c^2 \gg 1$). So, your calculations lead to the same result: $F=K/R$ for ultrarelativistic electrons. And, of course, this is different from Newtonian $F=2K/R$